# Inline MathJax not working with PageDown

Tags: javascript, django, mathjax

I'm trying to implement [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) and [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) in my **Django** application.          I followed insctructions [here](http://somesquares.org/blog/2013/4/integrating-mathjax-and-markdown-django/).
My code is working properly and Mathjax is running as it should, except that it doesn't render inline equations.

I've added all required files(`Markdown Converter`, `Markdown Sanitizer`, `Markdown Editor`, `Mathjax` and `Mathjax editing` - *as described in tutorial*)

I'm initializing plugins with code:

```
var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

            converter1.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
                return text.replace(/^ {0,3}""" *\n((?:.*?\n)+?) {0,3}""" *$/gm, function (whole, inner) {
                    return "<blockquote>" + rbg(inner) + "</blockquote>\n";
                });
            });

            var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
            var postfix = "";
            euni.mathjaxEditing.prepareWmdForMathJax(editor1, postfix, [["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"]]);

            editor1.run();
```

How can i get Mathjax to render inline equations?
As mentioned above, thing like `$$2x+5$$` work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable inline equations:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
 tex2jax: {
  inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
  processEscapes: true
}
```

});

See this older post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/mathjax-inline-mode-not-rendering